# How to ask say "or" in an if-statement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, if-statement

```
private void caseTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var CTcase = caseTextBox.Text;
            caseTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

            if (CTcase == "THRUHOLE") 
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "0";
            }
            else if (CTcase == "EIAA")
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "1";
            }
            else if (CTcase == "EIAB")
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "2";
            }
            else if (CTcase == "EIAC")
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "3";
            }
            else if (CTcase == "EIAD")
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "4";
            }
            else
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "error";
            }
        }
```

In each statement there are 3 values that it could equal to display the correct number. But I don't want to write 15 `if`/`else` statements to make it work. I tried using `||`, `|`, `&`, and `&&`. But I keep getting an error that says

> Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

```
 private void caseTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var CTcase = caseTextBox.Text;
            caseTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;

            if (CTcase == "THRUHOLE") 
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "0";
            }
            else if (CTcase == "EIAA" || "1206")
            {
                displayLabel3.Text = "1";
            }
```

Comment: Can you post your code where you use the operators?

Comment: While you have accurate answers, this really needs a rethink. These items are name/value pairs, some kind of dictionary and simple lookup in one or two lines of code would be a lot neater.

Comment: @SpaceBison What about an enum ?

Comment: Yeah an enumeration could also work, however that still probably needs if/else

Comment: Switch fits enum the best :)

Comment: @MajkeloDev - see the answer below regarding the dictionary - this is a better solution than an enum, as you'd still need "if input == MyEnum.MyValueA" if using an enumeration. Enumerations ideally have a finite set of values, not a potentially changing set.

Comment: @SpaceBison for this particular it might be better. But if You would like to use this in many places - enum wins because it's  more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
if (CTcase == "THRUHOLE" || CTcase == "something else") 
        {
            displayLabel3.Text = "0";
        }
```

But - for cases like this one - use enum. It's much more readable !
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Answer (score 6):

I'd rather *eliminate* all *ifs* (which look *ugly* when being in great number and complicated) and create a single *dictionary* instead:

```
Dictionary<String, String> labels = new Dictionary<String, String>() {
  {"THRUHOLE", "0"},
  {"EIAA", "1"},
  {"1206", "1"},
  {"EIAB", "2"},
  {"EIAC", "3"},
  {"EIAD", "4"},
};

...

String text;

if (labels.TryGetValue(CTcase, out text)) 
  displayLabel3.Text = text;
else
  displayLabel3.Text = "error";
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two operators that will probably do the trick.

`|` is an `or` which will cause all statements in the `if` to be executed prior to evaluation.

`||` is an `or else` which will cause the statements to be executed from left to right until a condition is met (at which point it stops testing further conditions).

In your case, you could do something like:

```
if (CTcase == "THRUHOLE" || CTcase == "some other value" || CTcase == "something else") 
{
    displayLabel3.Text = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be using || improperly. It has to be a full statement in itself.

such as:

```
if(CTcase == "THRUHOLE" || CTcase == "somethingelse")
{
    displaylabel3.Text = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should worki:

```
CTcase = caseTextBox.Text;

if (CTcase == "test" || CTcase  == "Test" || CTcase  == "TEST")
{

}
```

My way to check if there is just a "writing error" i would do the following:

```
CTcase = caseTextBox.Text.ToLower();

if (CTcase == "test")
{

}
```

But this only works if you don't want to make a differnce between "Test" and "test".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can extend the method of string class like this

```
public static class StringExtension
{
    public static bool In(this string source, params string[] matches)
    {
        return matches.Contains(source);
    }
}
```

And then use it in your program, without worrying about to many if-clause

```
string displayLabel = string.Empty;
string CTcase = "EIAA";

if (CTcase.In("THRUHOLE"))
{
    displayLabel = "0";
}
else if (CTcase.In("EIAA", "1206"))
{
    displayLabel = "1";
}
```

I hope this may help you.